# Emacs - random color theme every hour?

Tags: emacs, random, elisp, color-scheme

I know that to `(funcall (car (nth (random (length color-themes)) color-themes)))` gives me a [random color theme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme#toc19) on every Emacs startup; but I hardly restart Emacs. How do I *cycle* between random color themes, say, every hour?

Comment: This sounds horrendous :) Is the idea to randomly select colour schemes until you stumble upon one that you want to keep?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(defun random-color-theme ()
  (interactive)
  (random t)
  (funcall (car (nth (random (length color-themes)) color-themes))))

(random-color-theme)

(run-with-timer 1 (* 60 60) 'random-color-theme)
```

Credit goes to `ggole` @ #emacs (freenode); and `aecrvol` (below) for the `(random t)` tip.

Comment: I am getting an error `void variable color-themes`. What should I do as prerequisite?

Answer (score 3):

A little improvment: adding to the function `(random t)`,
otherwise generated sequence will be the same in each Emacs run (
from http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Random-Numbers.html).

```
(defun random-color-theme ()
  (interactive)
  (random t)  ; randomazing
  (funcall (car (nth (random (length color-themes)) color-themes))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my update:

```
(setq color-themes (custom-available-themes))

(defun random-color-theme ()
  (interactive)
  (random t)
  (load-theme
   (nth (random (length color-themes)) color-themes)
   t))


(random-color-theme)

(run-with-timer 1 (* 60 60) 'random-color-theme)
```